# Windows 10 wallpaper background (Spring)

Tags: identify-this, photography

I saw this lovely photo on my windows 10 lock screen but I couldn't figure out its location. Clicking the "like what you see" button in the top right corner of the screen does not provide me any locational information. Please forgive me if this is a duplicate post.

Also: sorry for the low quality photo. For some reason, my computer wouldn't allow me to take a screenshot of the picture, so I had to use my phone.

Edit: This was marked as a duplicate. However, the post that supposedly had the answer to my question does not answer my question whatsoever. Again, clicking the "Like what you see?" button does not solve my problem. Also, clicking the "Spring means a flowering of new movie releases" does not give me any information about the image.
[image: picture]

Comment: What happens when you click on "Spring means a flowering of..."?

Comment: Also, could you extract the original image from C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_*\LocalState\Assets

Comment: I get linked to some microsoft site I believe--no information provided on the location of the picture. Also, I checked the folder you mentioned above. I found dozens of lock screen pictures (Ronda, Spain; some waterfalls Iceland, etc.), but none of them matched the one I posted. After checking the Assets folder, I checked the StagedAssets folder and found several more lock screen pictures, but still none matching the image I posted.

Comment: Not a dupe. OP's image is an exception.

Comment: Microsoft used to give you the name of the image but they changed it a while ago so now you are stack with an image you will never see again... :/

Comment: It's a dead ringer for Zakopane, Poland, but really, it could be anywhere (I haven't covered the entire Earth!)

Comment: Go to Settings.  Choose the Personalization setting. Select the Lockscreen tab.  Under Picture, either choose Windows Spotlight to enable, or another choice to disable `Windows Spotlight.

Also, you can choose to enable or disable the Get fun facts, tips,
tricks, and more on your lock screen toggle.

Comment: Reopening. OP's image is not a regular one since Spotlight shows an advertisement rather than the location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** I was wrong. Here is the correct answer, **it is [Hohenzollern castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohenzollern_Castle)  in the [Swabian Alps](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Hohenzollern+Castle/@48.3162556,8.9766066,3154m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x22ce7030d9455a2f!8m2!3d48.3235588!4d8.9674035)**. You can find [almost the exact same picture here with Getty](http://www.gettyimages.de/detail/foto/elevated-view-towards-hohenzollern-castle-and-stock-fotografie/530354274). It appears to have been taken from [Zellhornwiese](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Zellerhornwiese/@48.3149055,8.9786116,1323m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x22ce7030d9455a2f!2sHohenzollern+Castle!8m2!3d48.3235588!4d8.9674035!3m4!1s0x0:0xdaf61d9db00bdd80!8m2!3d48.3137283!4d8.9780831). The pic is labelled as "sunset", i.e. the view is towards north-west from the clearing.

A similar view is available from [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Burg_Hohenzollern#/media/File:ZellerHorn.jpg):
[image]

Note the characteristic foot of the castle hill when the tree height changes. One might even be able to match some of the trees in the foreground, see also the Google maps satellite view above.

Old post:
By no means certain but I
[find](https://www.shutterstock.com/de/image-photo/aerial-view-on-romantic-fairy-castle-502468771?src=8zuos2dDBo2il9cOOLlGUQ-1-25)
[a](https://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fthumb1.shutterstock.com%2Fdisplay_pic_with_logo%2F3749567%2F502605457%2Fstock-photo-aerial-view-on-romantic-fairy-castle-in-picturesque-autumn-landscape-lit-by-evening-sun-castle-on-502605457.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shutterstock.com%2Fsearch%2Faerial%2Bczech%2Bview&docid=b2bko7iIxd_3kM&tbnid=qtZ7VjWaUCq1MM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiatIy9povTAhWEK8AKHcK1BH0QMwiDAShcMFw..i&w=450&h=358&bih=925&biw=1920&q=bouzov%20castle%20aerial%20view&ved=0ahUKEwiatIy9povTAhWEK8AKHcK1BH0QMwiDAShcMFw&iact=mrc&uact=8#h=358&imgrc=qtZ7VjWaUCq1MM:&vet=10ahUKEwiatIy9povTAhWEK8AKHcK1BH0QMwiDAShcMFw..i&w=450)
[lot](https://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.mnn.com%2Fassets%2Fimages%2F2016%2F04%2Fbuzov-castle.jpg.990x0_q80_crop-smart.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mnn.com%2Flifestyle%2Feco-tourism%2Fblogs%2Faerial-views-fairy-tale-castles-around-world&docid=t0yrlHeqAH5qDM&tbnid=0CumE8xQVzvsUM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiug6-qpYvTAhXmJ8AKHZtoDGI4ZBAzCEsoSTBJ..i&w=990&h=673&bih=925&biw=1920&q=bouzov%20castle&ved=0ahUKEwiug6-qpYvTAhXmJ8AKHZtoDGI4ZBAzCEsoSTBJ&iact=mrc&uact=8#h=673&imgrc=0CumE8xQVzvsUM:&vet=10ahUKEwiug6-qpYvTAhXmJ8AKHZtoDGI4ZBAzCEsoSTBJ..i&w=990)
[of](https://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.czechtourism.com%2Fgetmedia%2Fbb48917b-3442-40de-ac1b-56520542ed45%2Fshutterstock_215848234.jpg.aspx%3Fext%3D.jpg%26maxsidesize%3D700%26width%3D575%26height%3D370%26crop%3D1&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.czechtourism.com%2Fc%2Fbouzov-castle%2F&docid=-Jcjn_oYEZ8xjM&tbnid=DaSaO3k7wDkvnM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjJhN6lpYvTAhWXOsAKHdwZCdsQMwg2KBAwEA..i&w=575&h=370&bih=925&biw=1920&q=bouzov%20castle&ved=0ahUKEwjJhN6lpYvTAhWXOsAKHdwZCdsQMwg2KBAwEA&iact=mrc&uact=8#h=370&imgrc=DaSaO3k7wDkvnM:&vet=10ahUKEwjJhN6lpYvTAhWXOsAKHdwZCdsQMwg2KBAwEA..i&w=575)
[pictures](https://www.shutterstock.com/de/image-photo/aerial-view-on-romantic-fairy-castle-473513989?src=8zuos2dDBo2il9cOOLlGUQ-1-16)
[that](https://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dronestagr.am%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F10%2Fimage6.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dronestagr.am%2Fczech-republic-bouzov%2F&docid=9G6e5PuOIM6wyM&tbnid=Li313d3qY8pk0M%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjJhN6lpYvTAhWXOsAKHdwZCdsQMwhyKEMwQw..i&w=4000&h=2296&bih=925&biw=1920&q=bouzov%20castle&ved=0ahUKEwjJhN6lpYvTAhWXOsAKHdwZCdsQMwhyKEMwQw&iact=mrc&uact=8#h=2296&imgrc=Li313d3qY8pk0M:&vet=10ahUKEwjJhN6lpYvTAhWXOsAKHdwZCdsQMwhyKEMwQw..i&w=4000)
make me believe this is [Bouzov castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouzov_Castle) in the [Czech Republic](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Bouzov+Castle/@49.7022632,16.8901143,1691m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x47126c10c30de927:0xcadf9e821136ccf8!8m2!3d49.7049411!4d16.8895083).

Note the castle in the right corner of your picture, and the vegetation matches with the Google maps of south of the castle. The shot would then be directed towards the sunset in the west.

Comment: I think you have it +1 and as close as anyone will come; well done

Comment: How did you find out?

Comment: I would not be surprised if you were correct @mts. Excellent detective work. I looked at dozens of pictures and the both the vegetation and the terrain of the castle's surroundings seem to match those of the picture. Thank you :)

Comment: @JonathanReez for the first (wrong) guess I did a Google image search for "castle hill sun trees" or something similar and then manually sifted through results. Then I went through the canonical which inspired me to search for "castle" in the Getty images DB and from there I got an almost immediate hit.

Comment: I searched "castle" on Getty images just now and I found the EXACT picture that I uploaded: http://www.gettyimages.com/license/591869953